# How to download an Image directly from the URL in some websites?

Tags: java

I was trying to download this image, directly from the full path. When I try it throw Firefox, I'm redirected to the initial page.
But into some Manga, i could see the url from image, and it's that one...
I'm using the code below... Someone knows why it's happening?

```
       URL url = new URL("http://mangas.centraldemangas.com.br/death_note/death_note001-01.jpg");
       InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
       ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       int n = 0;
       while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
       {
          out.write(buf, 0, n);
       }
       out.close();
       in.close();
       byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

       String nomeArquivo = "teste.jpg";

       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://ImagensAnime//"+nomeArquivo);
       fos.write(response);
       fos.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Is there any way to download it using this URL directly?

Comment: Four spaces is enough for a reasonable indentation. 100 spaces is a bit much, you think?

Comment: Why not simply use the URL in ImageIO's `read(URL url)` method?

Comment: Why *what* is happening?

Comment: This is done to try and stop you from doing what you're trying do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely they are checking the HTTP REFERRER (with mod_rewrite maybe) and if it doesn't match their domain it will redirect you to the homepage.

Try setting HTTP-REFERRER to `http://centraldemangas.com.br/` and see if that works.

Comment: I tryed it another way and figured it out ;D Thanks